# Xaml AbsoluteLayout Proportional flag does not behave as expected

Tags: android, visual-studio, xaml, xamarin

I'm new to XAML and Xamarin so this may be something everyone is simply used to but I was hoping someone could explain it to me:

```
<Label Text="Relax" Font="20" TextColor="White" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 50, 1000,1000"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"></Label>
```

So I have this label nested in an `AbsoluteLayout` with no custom properties to it. The label is set to be 50 pixels from the top of the screen and 50% from the side (or in the middle of the screen horizontally). When I run this, the label does not even appear on the screen:

[image: No label]

But as soon as I add `HorizontalOptions="Center"` to its properties it behaves exactly as expected:

[image: Label appears]

So when I copy the original properties of the label (note without the horizontal options):

```
<BoxView Color="Black" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 50, 100,100"  AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"></BoxView>
```

It behaves exactly as expected:

[image: Boxview]

So as I said before, I have the solution to positioning the image correctly, so rather I would simply like an explanation as to why the boxview positions itself correctly while the label with exactly the same properties requires a `HorizontalOptions="Center"` property

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your codes:

```
<Label Text="Relax" 
       Font="20" 
       TextColor="White" 
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 50, 1000,1000"   
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="XProportional"></Label>
```

The `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds` has set the label's width and height to 1000, if you add `BackgroundColor="Yellow"` into your `Label`, and run your project, you will see the label's area( yellow area) in your screen. The "Relax" text exists on the left and top corner of the `1000*1000`'s area, but it is outside of your screen, so you can't see it. If you use `AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5, 50, 100,100"`, like your `BoxView`, you will see the `Label`.

About `HorizontalOptions="Center"`, it will put your "Relax" text on `1000*1000`'s center in the horizontal, if you also add `VerticalOptions="Center"`, your "Relax" text will be put on `1000*1000`'s center( both horizontal and vertical's center), it will be below your screen(outside of your screen), so you can't see it. You can test it with `100*100` or maybe `500*500`.